Using Bayes's Equation For Getting Out of Bed
I want to know if I'm using Bayes's Equation correctly.
I don't get out of bed when the alarm goes off.  My goal is to arise at first bells (no snoozing!). I'm keeping track of my progress and using Bayes's Equation to calculate the probability that I will get out of bed at first bells given that I will have told myself to get out of bed at first bells when I go to sleep.
P(A) = the probability that I will get out of bed at first bells.
P(B) = the probability that I will have told myself to get out of bed at first bells when I go to sleep.
P(B|A) = the probability that I will tell myself to arise the night before because I arose that morning.
P(A|B) = the probability that I will arise at first bells because I told myself to the night before.
On the first morning it looked like this:
Arose at first bells = 1
Did not arise at first bells = 0
Told myself to arise at first bells = 1
Did not tell myself to arise at first bells = 0
I calculated:
P(A) = 100%
P(B) = 100%
P(B|A) = 100%
P(A|B) = 100%
On my second morning:
Arose at first bells = 1
Did not arise at first bells = 1
Told myself to arise at first bells = 2
Did not tell myself to arise at first bells = 0
I calculated:
P(A) = 50%
P(B) = 100%
P(B|A) = 50%
P(A|B) = 25%
On my third morning:
Arose at first bells = 1
Did not arise at first bells = 2
Told myself to arise at first bells = 3
Did not tell myself to arise at first bells = 0
I calculated:
P(A) = 33.33%
P(B) = 100%
P(B|A) = 33.33%
P(A|B) = 11.11%
On my fourth morning, it looked like this:
Arose at first bells = 1
Did not arise at first bells = 3
Told myself to arise at first bells = 4
Did not tell myself to arise at first bells = 0
I calculated:
P(A) = 25%
P(B) = 100%
P(B|A) = 25%
P(A|B) = 6.25%
Am I doing this correctly?  It struck me as add that P(A|B) is falling so fast.  Is Bayes's Equation the right tool for this little experiment.  My goal was to use the equation with a simple, real-life example, so that I could become more familiar with using it and seeing its application.
Clearly, telling myself to wake up at first bells the night before is not working.  (This is a good example of the old adage, "Action Talks, Bull**** Walks.)
If I were to try something else, like going to bed an hour earlier, I would start again and see where that takes me.  And depending on the results, determine if I should try something else, or if I found the right behavior to get me out of bed at first bells.  LOL.
Thanks,
Philip
